# Using information stored in database to generate the nodes for a Tree using struts 2 and ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, treeview, struts2

I need to develop a tree to display the hierarchy of categories on a retail site. For example

```
-Clothing
  - Men
     - Trousers
     - Shirts
  - Women
```

I'm working on struts and using the struts dojo plugin to use this tag :

```
<sx:tree id="root" label="Category">
```

For the other child nodes, the data is stored in a database. If I use

```
    .......
while( rs.next())
  {
            %>
            <sx:tree id="child1" label ="<%=rs.getString("Category")%>" />
            <%
    }
......
```

the compiler tells me that expressions can't be used as value for the label attribute.

Can anyone suggest a workaround or any alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Struts 2, but looking at the documentation does the following work:

```
%>
<s:set name="categoryValue">
    <%= rs.getString("Category") %>
</s:set>
<sx:tree id="child1" label="#categoryValue" />
<%
```

That being said, it is probably a better idea to iterate over the result set and create a collection based off of it in Java code and have the JSP iterate over that collection instead of the result set. The code would end up being cleaner.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. Yes I am using a collection. I had forgotten the quotes and I'd just used #categoryValue(as in your example).

Comment: Hey, it doesn't seem to work.

<s:set name="categoryValue" value= "%{'<%=rs.getString("category")%>'}">
</s:set>
<sx:treenode id="child1" label ="%{#categoryValue}"/>

The error I get is 

"/jsp/tree.jsp(249,65) equal symbol expected"

However if i give

<s:set name="categoryValue" value= "%{'Test'}">, the value Test is obtained.

Comment: Shouldn't the <%= rs.getString("Category") %> be nested inside as the body of the <s:set> tag instead of as the value of the element value? Or perhaps try value="<%= rs.getString('Category') %>" instead.